# Facebook server-side login, CORS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, go, cors, beego

I'm implementing a web site with FB server-side login as simplified steps below:

1. A simple button triggers JS script which calls my backend API `https://localhost/fblogin`

   ```
   function sendFbLoginData() {
       $.get("https://localhost/fblogin", function(data, status) {});
   }
   ```
2. In the backend handler of /fblogin the user is redirected to FB login dialog for requesting permissions and access token.

   ```
   func (ct *LoginController) FbLogin() {
       url := "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost/fboauth2cb&response_type=code&scope=public_profile"
       ct.Redirect(url, 302)
       return
   }
   ```
3. At browser console shows error msg:

   ```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_ur…e_type=code&scope=public_profile. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
   ```

After googling I realize this is a CORS problem. Since I cannot change Facebook's behavior, how do I deal with this problem? or fundamentally I do fb server-side login in a wrong way?

ps. my env is AWS + Beego (golang)

Comment: how did you solve it after all?

Comment: @Matt, let users login at client side, get info such as name, email, short-term token and expiration time, pass to server via https. If you need long-term token, please check FB doc.  :)

Comment: @Matt not sure if its still relevant, my current workaround is: return auth url to client (without redirect) and set `window.location.hreh = authUrl`. Still can't understand why this approach works and redirect doesn't

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ask for `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...` from JavaScript and wait for its results; that page is intended to be shown in a browser, so that Facebook can ask the user for its credentials and permission to use his account in your app.

So, instead of:

```
    $.get("https://localhost/fblogin", function(data, status) {});
```

you should use something like:

```
    location = "https://localhost/fblogin";
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app settings in Facebook in settings tab (somewhere like `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app-id}/settings/`)you should set your site URL to `https://localhost/` so it can recognize it as a valid redirect

Comment: yeah i've already added in my app setting -> basic -> website -> site URL, but doesn't help. thanks for responding anyway!